# Adobe LiveCycle - checked check box not hiding subforms

Tags: checkbox, adobe, visibility, livecycle, subform

I am creating a PDF form in Adobe LiveCycle that has sections that can be check boxed "None" and the section (subform(s)) will "disappear" (become hidden). This is done in the Action Builder with the condition when check box is checked, set the visibility of the subform to hidden. There is also an opposite action, when the "None" check box is unchecked, the hidden section will become visible. This works with most of the check boxes/subforms on the form, but some will not work (stay visible no matter what).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out LifeCycle did not like my subform naming convention. The ones that worked were called "SubformNumber". The ones that didn't were "SubformNumber.Number". I changed those to "SubformNumberLetter" and that worked!